# Find classes in css file and write them in a new file with python

Tags: python, css, string-parsing

I have a .css file, not indented, with some classes definitions. I need to extraxt all the classes that start with `.icon` , for example:

```
.icon_arrow:before {
    content="/256"
}
```

And write them in a new file. I tried to read all the lines and write the string between `.icon` and `}`, like this:

```
infile = open('myfile.css', 'r')
outfile = open('newfile.css', 'w')
copy = False

with infile as css:
    for line in css:
        if line.strip() == ".icon":
            copy = True
        elif line.strip() == '}':
            copy = False
        elif copy:
            outfile.write(line)
```

But I get an empty file.
Suggestions?

Comment: **I need to extraxt all the classes that start with .icon** so it should be `line.strip().startswith('.icon')` instead of `line.strip() == ".icon"`.

Comment: Even so @a_python_user, that will only write the content within the class and not the class name and its closing bracket (it will only write `content="/256"` to the file).

Comment: I get anyway an empty file

Comment: @Danny_DD there are CSS parsers that are already written for you. You'd be better off using one of those, as writing a parser is inherently very very difficult.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I solved at the end with:

```
regex = r"(\.icon\w+.(.*?)\})"
classes = re.findall(regex, infile.read())

for entry in classes:
    outfile.write(entry[0] + '\n')
```

Answer (score 0):

I think this solves your problem:

```
import re

textfile = open('myfile.css', 'r')
filetext = textfile.read()

matches = re.findall("^\.icon.*\n+.*\n+}", filetext, re.MULTILINE)

print(matches)

outfile = open('newfile.css', 'w')

for match in matches:
  outfile.write(match)
```

myfile.css

```
.icon_arrow:before {
    content="/111"
}

.icon_arrow:before {
    content="/222"
}

.icon_arrow:before {
    content="/333"
}

.somethingelse:before {
    content="/444"
}

.somethingelse:before {
    content="/555"
}
```

print(matches) will print:

```
['.icon_arrow:before {\n    content="/111"\n}', '.icon_arrow:before {\n    content="/222"\n}', '.icon_arrow:before {\n    content="/333"\n}']
```

Comment: `matches` is empty :\

Comment: No way, check the print(matches), it gives me the correct response.